# Can't return dynamic string from a function

Tags: c++, string

I was writing some code challenge from reddit about encrypting strings and I came up with something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string encrypt(string sentence);

int main()
{
    string sentence;
    int i = 0;
    cout << "Welcome. Enter a sentence: ";
    getline(cin, sentence);
    cout << sentence << endl;
    encrypt(sentence);
    cout << endl << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

string encrypt(string sentence)
{

    int i = 0;
    int x = (sentence.size());
    string *encrypted_sentence = new string[sentence.size()];
    int *wsk = new int[sentence.size()];
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        wsk[i] = sentence[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        if (wsk[i] == ' ')
            continue;
        else if (islower(wsk[i]))
        {
            if (wsk[i] <= 99)
                wsk[i] = (wsk[i] + 23);
            else
                wsk[i] = (wsk[i] - 3);
        }
        else
        {
            if (wsk[i] <= 67)
                wsk[i] = (wsk[i] + 23);
            else
                wsk[i] = (wsk[i] - 3);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        //cout << static_cast <char> (wsk[i]);
        encrypted_sentence[i] = wsk[i];
    }

    return *encrypted_sentence;
}
```

My problem is, that there is nothing that gets returned. After I run the program I get nothing in return. Can anybody point me in the right direction with this? What have I missed?

Comment: You're returning a `std::string` in the `main` (Edit: apparently, i was just confused by the indentation)? (you even declared the return type `void`, it's usually `int` to return an error code btw) Why don't you simply print your string with `std::cout` (Edit: same here)?

Comment: My function (string encrypt) suppose to return the string. About that std::cout - it's cool, but I would want to do sth other next with this string

Comment: I think you want [this](http://ideone.com/gO8k4C).

Comment: @Caninonos YES! Thank You very much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code is obviously wrong. string *encrypted_sentence = new string[sentence.size()]; allocates an ARRAY of strings! Not a single string. Judging from that, you can see how your code is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

First `main()` returns an `int` **always**.  `void main()` is not standard.  Secondly:

```
string encrypted_sentence = new string[sentence.size()];
```

Will not even compile.  `encrypted_sentence` is of type `std::string` but you are trying to assign to it a `std::string *`.  Third [you should avoid using `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

**Update:**

I believe you are trying to output the encrypted string at:

```
cout << endl << endl;
```

But all this is doing is outputting 2 newlines and flushing the output twice.  If you want to display the encrypted string then you either need to capture the return of the `encrypt()` function and display it or `encrypt()` can take the string in by reference.  IF you change `encrypt()` to take a reference then it would become:

```
void encrypt(string & sentence)
{
    string *encrypted_sentence = new string[sentence.size()]; // get rid of this line as it is not needed.
    //...
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        sentence[i] = wsk[i];
    }
}
```

And then you would output the string with:

```
cout << sentence << endl;
```

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to change it back before posting it here (I tried a lot of stuff). It's: string *encrypted_sentence = new string[sentence.size()]; of course.

Comment: @T.T. Then you should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32206377/edit) your question with what you actually have.

Comment: Done. Sorry. New here.

Comment: Great! I'll try it this way now. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone would seek an answer to this question, I've come up with this, and I'm pretty sure it finally works how I wanted it to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string encrypt(std::string to_encrypt);

int main()
{
std::string sentence;
std::string result;
std::cout << "Welcome. Please enter a sentence: ";
getline(std::cin, sentence);
result = encrypt(sentence);
std::cout << "Result: " << result << std::endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}

std::string encrypt(std::string to_encrypt)
{
int i = 0;
int x = (to_encrypt.size());
std::cout << std::endl << "x = " << x << std::endl;
int *temp = new int[to_encrypt.size()];
for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    temp[i] = to_encrypt[i];
}

for (i=0; i < x; i++)
{
    if (temp[i] == ' ')
        continue;
    else if (islower(temp[i]))
    {
        if (temp[i] <= 99)
            temp[i] = temp[i] + 23;
        else
            temp[i] = temp[i] - 3;
    }
    else
    {
        if (temp[i] <= 67)
            temp[i] = temp[i] + 23;
        else
            temp[i] = temp[i] - 3;
    }
}
std::string encrypted;
for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    encrypted += (static_cast <char> (temp[i]));
}
return encrypted;

}
```